# Qt Application Calling Dll from Fortran

Tags: windows, qt, fortran

Here's the problem I got for Qt Application(Qt4\Qt5) calling Dlls from Fortran(CVF\IVF).

**Qt4+Dll(CVF)+WinXp**

1. It works fine **in my PC** both in QtCreator and as solo.
2. not working in other's (xp or win7/8)
3. the error is "dll not loaded" ( .isLoaded() false message)

then my PC's dead, got new one and immigrated to Qt5 with IVF.
But still the problem:

**Qt5+Dll(IVF with complier_platform win32)+Win8**

1. It works fine **in my PC** both in QtCreator and as solo
2. not working in other's (xp or win7/8)
3. the error is "dll not loaded" ( .isLoaded() false message)

Well, after trying them from various PCs:

1. I suppose it's not the platform problem(32bit or 64)
2. I am sure the dll path is correct when calling

Qt calling codes are

```
 if(stlDll.load()){
  myfun fun1 = (myfun)stlDll.resolve("STLDLL");       
  if ( fun1 ){ 
      fun1(fileName_For90);  
  }
}
else
    QMessageBox::information(NULL, "File Missing",tr("dll not loaded, the Directory is ")+dllPath, QMessageBox::Ok);
```

the error is always "**dll not loaded**", however that's the very right dllPath where I can find the dll with eyeballs but the Qt Applicaiton can not.

Fortran dll compiling codes are :

```
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT,ALIAS::stlDLL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically DLL's compiled with Intel Fortran are dynamically linked to the Intel Fortran (and underlying Microsoft C++) runtime DLL's.  Are your Fortran DLL's compiled and linked that way?

If so, you need to have the Intel Fortran runtime DLL's (and the underlying Microsoft C++ runtime DLL's) installed on the target machine.

You can get installation packages for the Intel Fortran runtime DLL's from the Intel website in the same manner that you acquire downloads of the compiler (or see [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/redistributable-libraries-for-the-intel-c-and-visual-fortran-composer-xe-for-windows/)).  You can get installation packages for the Microsoft C++ runtime libraries by searching the Microsoft website (they are Visual Studio version and service pack specific).  Alternatively, merge modules and installation exe's for the runtimes may have been installed on your machine as part of the Intel Fortran and Visual Studio installations.

Comment: thanks, but win8 seems not included in the OS supported from your link.`The supported OS are: Windows XP*, Vista*, Windows 7*, Windows Server 2003*, Windows Server 2008*, Windows HPC Server 2008*.` and if it's a dll compiling problem, why works well in my own PC?

Comment: On your machine the compiler runtime will have been installed when you installed the compiler itself.  The link was to an older version of the Intel compiler (xe2011), released prior to Windows 8, just as an example (you don't state the version of Intel Fortran or Visual Studio you are using).  In that article there is a link for runtimes of a later version of the compiler (xe2013).  Searching the Intel website (or even better, logging in and using their software registration and download site) will give you access to other versions.

Comment: I just solved it: missing 2 dlls for IVF(LIBIFCOREMD.DLL & LIBMMD.DLL) detected by DependencyWalker. Thanks anyway, you suggestion really helps.

Comment: Those two DLL's are some of the Intel Fortran runtime DLL's.  Installation of the Fortran runtime installs those two DLL's (and others).

Comment: yes, you are right. And to other guys who might be stuck in such problem: if you want your app to run ok in other PCs without IVF installed, u probably need to put them in the application file.